# Nested Associations in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Quick question about best practices for APIs.

I have a `User` model that `belongs_to` a `Role` model.

The `Role` model has two possible predefined values: 'Organizer' and 'Judge'.

Instead of creating a new `User` the normal Rails way:

```
user: { 
    first_name: 'Sample', 
    last_name: 'User', 
    role: { 
        id: 1, 
        label: 'organizer' 
} }
```

I'd like the users of my API to be able to create users like so:

```
user: {
    first_name: 'Sample',
    last_name: 'User',
    role: 'organizer'
}
```

Since I have the `belongs_to: :role` attached in my `User` model, I can't permit the `:role` attribute in my parameters and then pass it a string, or I get an error.

Is there some nice way to do this in Rails 4 without adding a ton of code?

Here's my `create` action in my `UsersController`:

```rb
def create
    @user = User.new( create_params )

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def create_params
    params.permit( :first_name, :last_name, :role )
end
```

Comment: what do you have in your controller?

Comment: Added the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't permit the role parameter then do something like

```
Role.where(:name => user_params[:role]).first << User.create(first_name => user_params[:first_name], :last_name = user_params[:last_name])
```

Also, considering the limited number of roles, maybe creating api endpoints for each of them would make sense or perhaps a catchall:

```
post '/api/v1/roles/:role_name' :to => 'user#create'
```

then:

```
Role.where(:name => params[:role_name]).first << User.create(first_name => user_params[:first_name], :last_name = user_params[:last_name])
```

Comment: That's a very cool first approach. I feel terrible that I hadn't seen the `<<` operator before just now used for associations. My only issue is that I need to be able to check for successful creation of the user, then return different HTTP responses based on that.